# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError - okhttp3 (Android)

Tags: android-studio, okhttp

My app keeps crashing. Can't figure out where the issue is.  I'm not even using okttp3 library.
Currently, I'm only using retrofit 1.9 and otto 1.3.8

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method callEnqueue(Lokhttp3/Call;Lokhttp3/Callback;Z)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.myproj.sample-2/base.apk)
at okhttp3.ws.WebSocketCall.enqueue(WebSocketCall.java:108)
at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.doOpen(WebSocket.java:73)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:75)
at io.socket.thread.EventThread.exec(EventThread.java:50)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.open(Transport.java:70)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.probe(Socket.java:458)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onOpen(Socket.java:471)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onHandshake(Socket.java:512)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:485)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$900(Socket.java:30)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:299)
at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:127)
at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling$2.call(Polling.java:124)
at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.decodePayload(Parser.java:251)
at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling._onData(Polling.java:134)
at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.onData(Polling.java:106)
at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(PollingXHR.java:113)
at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: retrofit seems to depend on okhttp  : See [pom.xml of retrofit](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/retrofit/retrofit/1.9.0/retrofit-1.9.0.pom)

Comment: @ymonad Ok, so what can be a possible solution to this problem.  I'm not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the help of [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/337) post.

Just add the following to your gradle dependecies.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these dependencies :

```
 implementation 'com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy3:3.2.3'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
```

Hope this may help you.