# Okhttp 3 and Socket.io conflict

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, okhttp

I have an app using [OkHttp3](http://socket.io/get-started/) and [Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) connecting to a node.js server

```
io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1
```

After a few requests of  the OkHttp client i try to connect a socket and then  it throws this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: EventThread
 Process: dge.cetic.panicbutton, PID: 18346
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Internal.callEnqueue
     at okhttp3.ws.WebSocketCall.enqueue(WebSocketCall.java:108)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.doOpen(WebSocket.java:73)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:75)
     at io.socket.thread.EventThread.exec(EventThread.java:50)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.open(Transport.java:70)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.probe(Socket.java:458)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onOpen(Socket.java:471)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onHandshake(Socket.java:512)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:485)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$900(Socket.java:30)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:299)
     at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:127)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.access$700(Polling.java:17)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling$2.call(Polling.java:124)
     at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.decodePayload(Parser.java:251)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling._onData(Polling.java:134)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.onData(Polling.java:106)
     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(PollingXHR.java:113)
     at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:75)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This error is thrown only when both libraries are used together and one after another.
As it show a Thread exception I tried:

1. enqueue() in the OkHttp client
2. Handler to run the socket connection on a Thread

but the errors still the same.
Could this be an issue in one of these libraries?

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092531/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-okhttp3-android) in my case, i forgot to update the ws package and it was pointing to the old version